# Convert IplImage to Mat in javacv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I need help to convert my `IplImage` into `Mat`. I want to compute `HOGDescriptor` for my image and then classify it with SVM, but "compute" requires `Mat` type.

Can you give some example of how to convert `IplImage` into `Mat` in java ?

Comment: convert IplImage to BufferedImage , then i think API will allow you to make image out of Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse the [official OpenCV Java binding](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) which is documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) and the [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) project which has no documentation.

If you're using `JavaCV`, you don't need to convert your `IplImage` in order to use the `HOGDescriptor`, as you can see in the [`JavaCV` source](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_objdetect.java), the `HOGDescriptor` object wrapper manipulates `CvArr` objects :

```
// javacv/cpp/opencv_objdetect.java:527
public static class HOGDescriptor extends Pointer {
    public HOGDescriptor();
    ...
    public native void setSVMDetector(CvArr _svmdetector);
    ...
    public native void compute(CvArr img, FloatPointer descriptors, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, CvPoint locations);
    public native void detect(CvArr img, CvPoint foundLocations, DoublePointer weights, double hitThreshold, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, CvPoint searchLocations);
    public native void detect(CvArr img, CvPoint foundLocations, double hitThreshold, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, CvPoint searchLocations);
    public native void detectMultiScale(CvArr img, CvRect foundLocations, double hitThreshold, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, double scale, int groupThreshold);
    public native void detectMultiScale(CvArr img, CvRect foundLocations, DoublePointer foundWeights, double hitThreshold, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, double scale, double finalThreshold, boolean useMeanshiftGrouping);
    public native void detectMultiScale(CvArr img, CvRect foundLocations, double hitThreshold, CvSize winStride, CvSize padding, double scale, double finalThreshold, boolean useMeanshiftGrouping);
    ...
};
```

Now, as you can see in [`opencv_core.java`](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.java), the `IplImage` wrapper object extends `CvArr` :

```
// javacv/cpp/opencv_core.java:410
public static class IplImage extends CvArr {
    ...
};
```

So you shouldn't have to do any conversion.

Here is an example using `HOGDescriptor.detectMultiScale`:

```
IplImage img = cvLoadImage("image.jpg");
CvRect foundRects = new CvRect(null);
HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor(); 
FloatPointer svm = HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector();
hog.setSVMDetector(svm);
hog.detectMultiScale(img, foundRects, 0, cvSize(8,8), cvSize(32,32), 1.05, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert IplImage to Mat is simple.

```
IplImage iplImage= cvLoadImage("image.png");

Mat matImage = new Mat(iplImage);
```

vice versa

Answer (score 1):

There's a method for that:

```
opencv_core.cvarrToMat(iplImage);
```