# How to convert IplImages/Frames got from FFmpegFrameGrabber to Mat

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

This is my code. I am using FFmpegFrameGrabber to grab frames one by one from a video stored in my android file system. I need some way to convert a IplImage or a Frame to a Mat so that I can perform some functions on it.

```
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber=new FFmpegFrameGrabber("/data/data/some.path.name/files/images/1.mp4");
        grabber.start();

        while(true){
        IplImage image=grabber.grab();
                   // or Frame image=grabber.grabFrame();


                   /*
           some code to convert Frame/IplImage to Mat.
                   */
                }

          grabber.stop();
          grabber.release();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert IplImage to Mat in javacv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584528/convert-iplimage-to-mat-in-javacv)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) has a constructor that takes an `IplImage`

```
 C++: Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)
```

There should also be one in your JavaCV.

On the other hand you should be able to use your `IplImage` directly with OpenCV without the need to convert to `cv::Mat`.

EDIT: Have a look at this Question on SO: [Convert IplImage to Mat in javacv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584528/convert-iplimage-to-mat-in-javacv)